# Android NDK not compiling

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk

I'm running Ubuntu Linux, and trying to compile native code for Android using the NDK.
The contents of my Android.mk file:

```
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)

   LOCAL_MODULE    := NativeDroid
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := org_me_nativedroid_mJNI.c

   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Its in the directory of that eclipse project.
My native code is in folder NativeDroid/jni, where NativeDroid is the project folder.

(From the command line):  and the errors I get

```
thomas@THOMASDESKLINUX:~/Documents/LinuxProgramming/EclipseWorkspace/Native Droid$ /home/thomas/Documents/LinuxProgramming/Android\ SDKs/android-ndk-r4b/ndk-build
dirname: extra operand `SDKs/android-ndk-r4b/ndk-build'
Try `dirname --help' for more information.
make: /home/thomas/build/core/build-local.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/thomas/build/core/build-local.mk'.  Stop.
```

Thanks in Advance!,
Dragonwrenn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved it
apparently having spaces in either the parent directories of the NDK and/or having spaces in the Eclipse project will cause ndk-build to fail.  strange.

Comment: I am getting this error when trying to compile Android Runtime (ART) for x86. My build command line is `ndk-build APP_ABI=x86 TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX= PRIVATE_SYSROOT_LINK= APP_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib   libs/x86/libMY_NATIVE_NAME.so -C $PWD NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$PWD APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk
` and my NDK is location at `/usr/local/src/android-sdk-linux_x86/ndk-bundle` (no spaces)

Answer (score 0):

HI 
the Android.mk file must be in the jni file